# DataSet com clausa where like '%' @parametro Visual Basic 2012

Tags: .net, vb.net, ado.net

Ola, estou criando um formulario para gerar relatorio utilizando o controle ReportViwer e me deparei com um problema, tenho um DataSet criado com nome de DsCliente, criei uma clausa para filtrar a pesquisa (DataSet Configuration), ao final da query do DataSet adiciona a seguinte clausula:

```
WHERE cliente_cnpj LIKE '%' + @clienteCnpj + '%'
```

onde o parâmetro @ClienteCnpj provem de uma textbox, porem na hora que finalizo ocorre um erro, dizendo que a syntax perto de @cliente esta errada, porem eu não encontro o erro!

Desde já agradeço!
esse é o codigo do formulario:

```
 Private Sub btnBuscar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBuscar.Click
    Me.clienteTableAdapter.Fill(Me.testebaseDataSet1.cliente,TextBox1.Text)
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End Sub
```

adicionei os controles ReportViwer, quando adicionei ele me pediu para criar um DataSet, criei o DataSet selecionei as tabelas, tudo funcionando perfeito, abri o DataSet no vb ele onde ele colocou a tabela que eu adicionei, selecionei Configure onde abriu uma janela com a query que eles esta executando:

```
SELECT cod_cliente, cliente_razaosocial, cliente_cnpj, cliente_cpf, cliente_codPraca, cliente_tipo, cliente_isencao, cliente_Redespacho, cliente_bloqueioCadastro, 
                     cliente_fantasia, cliente_ColetaCidade, cliente_ColetaBairro, cliente_ColetaUf, cliente_ColetaCep, cliente_ColetaHorario, cliente_ColetaEndereco, 
                     cliente_ExpedicaoBairro, cliente_ExpedicaoCep, cliente_ExpedicaoContato, cliente_ExpedicaoSigla, cliente_ExpedicaoObs, cliente_ExpedicaoData, 
                     cliente_ExpedicaoTelefone, cliente_ExpedicaoEndereco, cliente_ExpedicaoCidade, cliente_ExpedicaoRamal, cliente_ExpedicaoEmail, cliente_ExpedicaoFax, 
                     cliente_ExpedicaoColeta, cliente_ExpedicaoFormaCalculo, cliente_ExpedicaoUf, cliente_ExpedicaoZona, cliente_ExpedicaoMercEspecial, cliente_msgColeta, 
                     cliente_msgExpedicao, cliente_msgCotacao, cod_cotacao, cliente_cobrancaEndereco, cliente_cobrancaBairro, cliente_cobrancaCidade, cliente_cobrancaContato, 
                     cliente_cobrancaCadastrado, cliente_cobrancaTelefone, cliente_cobrancaCalculo, cliente_cobrancaDataCobranca, cliente_cobrancaFinalizado, 
                     cliente_cobrancaEmissao, cliente_cobrancaDataVEncimento, cliente_cobrancaSituacao, cliente_cobrancaUf, cliente_cobrancaObs, cliente_cobrancaUltimaAlteracao, 
                     cliente_cobrancaCep, cliente_inscricaoEstado, cliente_ColetaNumero, cliente_ZONA, cliente_cep, cliente_uf, cliente_numero, cliente_Bairro, cliente_Endereco, 
                     cliente_Cidade, cliente_telefone, cliente_contato FROM cliente
```

ao final adicionei a linha `WHERE cod_cliente LIKE '%' + @clienteCnpj + '%'`
quando clico em finish ele da erro dizendo que tem erro na syntax =\

Comment: O @clienteCnpj indica que irá entrar um parametro na sua query, pode descreve melhor seu problema?

Comment: @Marconi eu segui esses passos dessa [video aula](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JjM49xDV8Bc) porem na clausa Where da erro...

Comment: Descreva melhor seu problema e tente adicionar mais trechos de código, o que realmente tentou.

Comment: @Marconi foram essas etapas que eu fiz.

Comment: Eu Hebert. Se você resolveu o problema, mesmo que mudando totalmente o código, seria legal postar abaixo uma resposta explicando como fez. Assim futuros visitantes desta página poderão se beneficiar da sua solução. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Estou me baseando na seguinte resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665129/use-of-sqlparameter-in-sql-like-clause-not-working)

remova os `%` da sua consulta:

```
WHERE cod_cliente LIKE @clienteCnpj
```

Então adicione elas ao adicionar os parametros:

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clienteCnpj", "%" + clienteCnpj + "%");
```

Comment: o report criou essas linhas: `Me.clienteTableAdapter.Fill(Me.testebaseDataSet1.cliente,'Paremetro Aqui'` e` Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()` dentro da função load, criei um botão e na função clique do botão coloquei `Me.clienteTableAdapter.Fill(Me.testebaseDataSet1.cliente, "%" + TextBox1.Text + "%")` como me passou mais não deu, diz que A conversão da seqüência de caracteres '%18%' no tipo 'Integer' não é válida, por isso o `%` vai na clausula nas configurações do dataset =)

Comment: @HebertdeLima Cara, pelo erro que deu é pq a coluna é do tipo inteira, ou o parâmetro é do tipo inteiro, não vai conseguir usar um where dessa forma. Provavelmente teu parâmetro tá com o tipo errado

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade fui verificar e sim o erro havia ocorrido por conta disso, o parametro era de um tipo e o valor de outro, mais ja concertei foi um detalhe que não percebi, mais ainda assim o erro de syntax continua, já tentei de tudo, tem outa forma de criar esse filtro sem ser usando o DataSet? muito obrigado fera!

Answer (score 0):

Precisa ver na resposta do @TobyMosque se o where esta fazendo com os campos certos provavelmente seu cod_cliente é int e o cliente_cnpj deve ser string.

Esse

```
WHERE cod_cliente LIKE @clienteCnpj
```

ou

```
WHERE cliente_cnpj LIKE @clienteCnpj
```